# xsl:when test for processing instruction

Tags: xslt

I´m trying to create a choose statement, which detects an processing instruction

```
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="chapter/descriptive/heading='processing-instruction("xm-replace_text")'">
        <xsl:template match="chapter/descriptive/heading"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:template match="chapter/descriptive/heading">
            <fo:block
             font-size="16pt"
             font-weight="bold"
             font-color="red"
             space-before="5mm"
             space-after="2mm">
                <xsl:number
                 count="chapter | task  | diagnosis | taskintervals | tools | lubrication | glossary"
                 format="1.1"
                 level="multiple"/>
                 &#160;
                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

is it not possible to test for processing instructions like this?

edit: xml input (is the full xml needed?)

```
...    
<chapter infoclass-1="description" prodclass-1="setup">
<descriptive prodclass-1="setup" infoclass-1="intro">
<heading><?xm-replace_text Themenangabe in Form einer Überschrift ?></heading>
...
```

Comment: PLease add your input XML. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a node test for a processing instruction is done literally e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xm-replace_text')">...</xsl:template>
```

would match a pi `<?xm-replace_text ...?>`.

With your example XML assuming you are trying to match the `heading` element containing that particular processing instruction then use

```
<xsl:template match="chapter/descriptive/heading[processing-instruction('xm-replace_text')]">...</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="chapter/descriptive/heading/processing-instruction('xm-replace_text')">...</xsl:template>
```

if you want to match the processing instruction itself.